# What is the fastest way to append and read data to an 3D Numpy Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, assign

My code be summarised as a **for loop** **(M~10^5-10^6 iterations)** over some function which sequentially produces data in the form **(W,N)-arrays** where **W~500** and **N~100** and I need to store these as efficiently as possible. Apart from saving data of this form, I would also like be able to access them as fast as possible.

So far, I tried:

- Creating a np.empty((M,W,N)),
- Starting from a (W,N)-array and appending data using np.append, np.vstack, np.hstack.

So far everything seems to pretty slow.

What is the fastest way to manage this?
Do I need to rely on 3rd-party packages like Dask? If so, to which ones?

Comment: Have you actually looked at a `np.empty((2,3,4))` array?  And tried `np.append` on it?  `numpy` indexing of a (M,W,N) is efficient, especially if using slices.  But 'growing' an array is in-efficient.  It is better to start with a empty list, `[]`, and use list append.  Then make the array with one call at the end.

Comment: Please provide some minimal code example that is affected by the described issue. Have you checked if 'some function' is slow on its own?